# Laravel Controller doesn't exist, even though it clearly exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The error I'm getting is that the controller doesn't exist even though I know it does, here's the code.

Route.php

```
Route::get('mdpay/template', array("uses" => "templateController@index"));
```

templateController.blade.php

```
class templateController extends BaseController {

  public function index()
  {
    echo "made it";
  }


}
```

Why might I be getting this error: Class TemplateController does not exist

================= UPDATE: ==================

Ok, so I've created the correct route, renamed my file, and corrected the class name and I'm still coming up with that error.

File Names:

templateController.php

```
// File Name: TemplateController.php
class TemplateController extends BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        // app/views/myView.blade.php
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('mdpay/template', array("uses" => "TemplateController@index"));
```

Still receiving Controller Doesn't Exist error. All my other controllers (3 others) are working except this one.

Comment: rename `templateController.blade.php` to `templateController.php` blade is for views, not for controllers.

Comment: Is your controller inside a subfolder? try extending from `\BaseController` with a leading ` \ `.

Comment: This problem comes when you rename a controller or any class. You also can't use `php artisan route:list` it won't work because it doesn't maches the controller class as you renamed it . You need to autoload all the classes including your renamed controller as well. So you should use `composer dumpautoload`. It will regenerate all autoloading classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using the standard composer classmap autoloader you need to `composer dumpautoload` everytime you create a new file.

So to create a new controller with the standard composer setup given by Laravel:

1. Create a new file in `app/controllers` named `TemplateController.php`
2. Open up terminal and run `composer dumpautoload`

*As previous users have said, only view files should end with `.blade.php`.*

Comment: It was the dumpautoload that fixed it. I am using composer. Didn't realize I needed to every time a controller was made. I'm developing remotely from phpstorm.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Laravel 8, add this line to your RouteServiceProvider.php (you can search it by using CTRL + P):

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
// File Name: TemplateController.php
class TemplateController extends BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        // return "made it"; // or
        // app/views/myView.blade.php
        return View::make('myView');
    }
}
```

Route for that:

```
Route::get('mdpay/template', array("uses" => "TemplateController@index"));
```

Use `blade` in a `Blade view`, i.e: `myView.blade.php` basically stored in `app/views/` folder. Read more about [blate template](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: Lol... @itachi, all the best :-)

Comment: I've updated my question, and the code because I'm still receiving that error after using this fix. I have 3 other controllers which work, just not this one oddly.

Comment: Did you use `TemplateController.php` for you controller's name ?

Comment: Check the updated code again, copy paste it @jamadri.

Comment: @jamadri, also run `composer dump-autoload` from command prompt.

Comment: @WereWolf The code was good, it was the composer dumpautoload command that needed to get ran.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers live in the `app/controllers` directory and should remain there unless you have your own namespaced structure.

The reason you're getting a `Class TemplateController does not exist` is because it doesn't, firstly, your class is called `templateController` and secondly, it exists as `templateController.blade.php` which wouldn't be loaded in this way.

Blade files are for views, and only views within `app/views` or a custom views directory should end with `.blade.php`.

Create the file `app/controllers/TemplateController.php` and add the following code to it.

```
class TemplateController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "made it";
    }

}
```

Now on the command line, run the command `composer dumpautoload` and change you route declaration to:

```
Route::get('mdpay/template', array('uses' => 'TemplateController@index"));
```

Now it should all work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Laravel 9 and the error is like `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException` and  `Target class <controller name> does not exist.` when trying `php artisan route:list` on terminal.

This is the setup that I do:

1. Add `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` to RouteServiceProvider.php
2. Add 'namespace App\Http\Controllers;' to the controller file.
3. Do `php artisan optimize` on terminal
4. (Just to make sure the route already there) Do `php artisan route:list` again on terminal, and the controller route should be displayed.