# How to view data retrieved in the controller in the view?

Tags: laravel, sqlsrv

I'm trying to retrieve data in my controller using sqlsrv database connection and I want to view the result in my test.blade.php

```
public function index()
{
    $cout_achat = DB::table('[DWH_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE]')
        ->select( DB::raw('SUM([MONTANT_LC]) as cout_achat'))
        ->get();
    return view('test', ['test' => $cout_achat]);
}
```

and the code in the view

```
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Laravel</title>
<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
<body>
echo {{$cout_achat}};
</body>
</html>
```

but when I try to access myapp/test I get : ** Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\wamp64\www\projetSovac\resources\views\test.blade.php) –**

Comment: The error is something else. check the route file. It says route couldn't be found.

Comment: `Route::get('/test', 'TableauDeBord@index')->name('test');` I added this to my web.php and i get a probleme saying that the controller doesn't exist

Comment: I fixed the route problem now it's saying **Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\wamp64\www\projetSovac\resources\views\test.blade.php)**

Comment: instead of echo {{$cout_achat}}; try to write {{$test}}

Comment: Maybe it's the same issue, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206342/laravel-controller-doesnt-exist-even-though-it-clearly-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 404 the route you have provided is completely ok, can you please tell us how you are calling this route.
And please double check any typo in controller name.

Now I would like to talk about some improvement in your code

First of all is that when you return the view like this in your controller

```
return view('test', ['test' => $cout_achat]);
```

The $cout_achat will be available with name $test in your blade file. So you should try to use the same naming convention like

```
return view('test', ['cout_achat' => $cout_achat]);
```

Or simple you can use compact() laravels helper function like this

```
return view('test', compact(cout_achat));
```

It will automatically pass $cout_achat in blade.

Now for echoing the variable in balde you don't need to use echo explicitly like

```
echo {{$cout_achat}};
```

You can echo variables like

```
{{$cout_achat}}
```

Anything else will be handled automatically by blade compiler.

Hope this will help.