# BadMethodCallException Method [getReport] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

> BadMethodCallException Method [getReport] does not exist.

But there is a method called `getReport()`.

other reports are working but first one is not working. i wrote exactly the  same codes.

There is a controller, but my laravel couldn't find it.

i tried:

```php
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

but it didn't work.

web.php->

```php
Route::get('/report/{id}', 'ReportController@getReport');

Route::get('/report2/{id}', 'ReportController@getReport2');
```

ReportController.php    ->

```
public function getReport(Request $request,$id)
{ $users=Users::find($id);
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.report', compact('users'));

  return $pdf->stream(); }
```

codes are working on my pc (Localhost) But they are not working on Host (Website)

Comment: Can you add your controller?

Comment: check the spelling of your function (getReport) associated with this controller: Route::get('/report/{id}', 'ReportController@getReport');

Comment: @JuliusFasema Public function getReport(Request $request,$id)

Comment: @DilipHirapara i didnt use artisan commands. i simply added the lines. it is interesting that codes are working properly on LOCALHOST

Comment: @SametBOZKURT Would be good if you can show the actual code? Controller and the way you're calling the route.

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak i forgot to mention that they are working properly on localhost.

Comment: in your controller is this what you have? Public function getReport(Request $request,$id). if true, then you have to Remove [Request $request] as you dont need it here because you are using get and passing id from url

Comment: @JuliusFasema i editted question. i am using id in my method. other reports method have the same lines. there is no mistake i think.

Comment: Try to dump the autoload `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @SamuilBanti thank you... i found that before you answered... or same... thank you a lot again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravel Controller doesn't exist, even though it clearly exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206342/laravel-controller-doesnt-exist-even-though-it-clearly-exists)

it solved my problem...

Create a new file in app/controllers named TemplateController.php
Open up terminal and run composer dumpautoload -> This line solved my problem.

Thank You all

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

```
public function getReport($id)
    { 
          $users=Users::find($id);
          $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.report', compact('users'));

          return $pdf->stream(); 
    }
```

Comment: i am sorry, same error. as i saied before your codes and my old codes workin properly on localhost. but it doesnt work on the net.